# R SAS to xlsx conversion script

Tags: r

I am attempting to write a script that allows me to quickly convert a folder of SAS datasets into .xlsx and same them in a different folder. Here is my current code:

```
require(haven)
require(openxlsx)

setwd(choose.dir())

lapply(list.files(pattern="*.sas7bdat"), function(x) {
  openxlsx::write.xlsx(haven::read_sas(x), path = paste0(choose.dir(),x,".xlsx"))
})
```

I keep getting the following error and I am not sure why:

```
 Error in saveWorkbook(wb = wb, file = file, overwrite = overwrite) : 
  argument "file" is missing, with no default
```

**Final Code** (thanks @oliver):

```
require(haven)
require(openxlsx)

setwd(choose.dir())

lapply(list.files(pattern="*.sas7bdat"), function(x) {
  openxlsx::write.xlsx(haven::read_sas(x), file = paste0(gsub("\\.sas7bdat$", "", basename(x)), ".xlsx"))
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `write.xlsx` doesn't have a `path` argument but instead uses a `file` argument. This is documented in the function as well, see `help("write.xlsx")`:

```
outdir <- choose.dir() #<== choose only directory once
lapply(list.files(pattern="*.sas7bdat"), function(x) {

  # Obtain the basename of the file, without SAS extension
  x_basename <- gsub('\\.sas7bdat$', '', basename(x))

  # Write the file to Excel
  openxlsx::write.xlsx(haven::read_sas(x), 
                       # Use "file" instead of "path"
                       file = paste0(outdir, x_basename, ".xlsx"))
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Good catch. Is there a way to remove the `".sas7bdat"` from the output (i.e., so it is just the dataset name then `.xlsx`)

Comment: change `x` with `gsub('\\.sas7bdat$, '', basename(x))` :-)